# Reading from an access database and populating an array based on two fields from different tables

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am writing an excel application that is essentially selects values based on user input. A user selects a project number, then can select from a list of tool types both of which pre-exist in the access database. However, if the project does not have that tool associated, I don't want that tool to show up in the listbox. For example, say a user has selected project number 15. There are 3 tools associated with this project, say their names are tool 'A', 'C', 'D'. In other words, tool B has nothing to do with this project.

I have two different database tables that I am looking at. One table has all the tool names and is named ToolNames. The other table has all the tool files that list the project association, it's called ToolFiles. So there can be multiple copies of tool 'C' in the database that just vary with the amount of data in them.

I really need to query the ToolNames table, based on input from the user which can be checked in the ToolFiles table. Take the project number, look through the ToolFiles database for tools, and then populate record names of the tools with that project number and then query the ToolNames database and only select the ToolNames that showed up in the ToolFiles database. The ToolFiles database can have multiple can have duplicated tool names.

This is the join statement I have thus far:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * " _
        & "FROM ToolNames t " _
        & "INNER JOIN ToolFiles f " _
        & "ON t.ToolName = f.Tool_Name " _
        & "WHERE f.Tool_Name = '" & theSelectedProjName & "' "
rs.Open strSQL  ' , cn, 3, 3
```

where ToolNames is the table I want the values from, ToolFiles is the table I want to compare the two tool names field to.

I know this is a complicated question, and it is difficult to explain. Let me know if there is anything I can clarify. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are connecting using msquery or what to query the data tables? An example of what you have tried will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not query the database by joining `ToolNames` to `ToolFiles`? Something like:

```
SELECT ToolName
FROM ToolNames t
INNER JOIN ToolFiles f
ON t.ToolID = f.ToolID
WHERE f.ProjectID = [ProjectID]
```

Comment: What exactly does the t and f stand for?

Comment: @Ranlou: Sorry, they are aliases for the table names. Instead of typing out the table name each time for each table you can alias the table name and refer to the alias instead of the full name.